# How to get the size of a large Linked List within 1 second?

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi i've been struggling to complete this homework question that was given to me.
The question is to count how many "ballots" are in a linked list. When i run the function through J-Unit every other test passes, except for when the list is very large "956142" to be exact, as one of the rules is that it needs to complete within 1 second. Counting the list using iteration cause the function to fail because its too slow, and using recursion gives me a stack overflow error.

I am just unsure as to how you would make the function run quicker.

Current code that i have.

```
    public int size() {

    int count=0;
    Ballot current = head;
    while(current !=null) {
        count++;
        current=current.next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This function might also help in understanding what im doing.

```
    public void addVote(String candidate, EmptyBallots ballots, Timestamp time) {       
    
    Ballot vote = ballots.remove();

    vote.fill(candidate, time);

    vote.next=null;

    if(head==null) {
        head=vote;
        tail=vote;
    }
    else {
        tail.next=vote;
        tail=vote;
    }
}
```

and the code for the test

```
    public void testFilledBallotSizeAdvanced() {
    
    // Case 1: Medium size
    assertTimeoutPreemptively(Duration.ofMillis(1000), () -> {
        EmptyBallots e = new EmptyBallots(mLimit);
        FilledBallots f = new FilledBallots();
        for(int i = 0; i < 573; i++)
            f.addVote(testcase3[i], e, new Timestamp());
        assertNotNull(f);
        assertEquals(573,f.size());
    });

    // Case 2: Large size
    assertTimeoutPreemptively(Duration.ofMillis(1000), () -> {
        EmptyBallots e = new EmptyBallots(xLimit);
        FilledBallots f = new FilledBallots();
        for(int i = 0; i < 956142; i++)
            f.addVote(testcase5[i], e, new Timestamp());
        assertNotNull(f);
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            assertEquals(956142,f.size());
    });

    currentMethodName = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```

Any help would be apprecatied.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of counting runtime, why not create a variable that will keep the current length?

Comment: Inside your `addVote` method you could increase the count of total ballots as you go. Obviously, you would need to be careful to reduce the count when removing items from the list.